# Laravel CSRF on second (third, etc.) ajax request

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

In a laravel application, I have a form which I submit by javascript. I added the `{{ csrf_field() }}` to the form and I am using the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

The first request works fine and as expected. But if I don't refresh the page and resend the same form (*for example because of form field validation errors*), I get a `419` error on my request. I think its because the `_token` is the same in both requests and somekind of invalidated on the first request.

Is there a way, to prevent a csrf token to be invalidated on a request, so that I can reuse it as long as I need it?

Comment: you added the csrf in the header of the request or in the form/data ?

Comment: In the form data (`{{ csrf_field() }}` is used)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the Axios HTTP library (it's included in bootstrap.js file) you will need to manualy update the CSRF token from the received cookies of the previous request.

> the Axios HTTP library provided in the `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file automatically sends an X-XSRF-TOKEN header using the value of the encrypted XSRF-TOKEN cookie. If you are not using this library, you will need to manually configure this behavior for your application.

--EDIT--
Since your pages are cached and static. either lose the caching or lose the CSRF
in  `app\Http\Kernel.php` comment the line for the middleware `VerifyCsrfToken`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, <--- THIS ONE
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckBlocked::class,
    ],

];
```

Comment: Thats not an real option. My pages are all static (cached) html files generated by Laravel.  So user1 and user2 are getting the same HTML file. Just the form is injected by js depending on the user session

Comment: @bernhardh you omitted to precise that your pages are static across the requests. edited the answer